# Nested resources in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, rest, rails-api

I have been working on a web app using a Rails API and AngularJS. As models I have Teams and Users. You can add existing users to your team at anytime.

Since I want to add users to a team from AngularJS I wonder which route / controller should handle this action. (Adding an existing users to team.users)

Would this be a **PUT** *api/teams/:id/users*
or **PUT** *api/teams/:id* or even a **POST** *to api/teams/:id/:users*

Keep in mind I am not creating a new user here but appending an existing one to a team's users.

Thank you!

Comment: Use POST to api/teams/:id/:users

more info

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Comment: Even though I am not *creating* a user ?

Comment: Yes as you are adding a user to a team. If you are creating a user you would post to api/users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above; I would POST to `/memberships`.

You're not creating or updating a user, and you're not creating or updating a team.

You're creating a new joining record for users and teams. I would call that type of record a `Membership`, and provide an API for managing them. When a user joins a team, it's a POST to `/memberships`. When a user leaves a team, it's a DELETE to `/memberships/:id`.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Would that require me to remove the has_and_belongs_to_many relationships I had and replace them with has_many through: ?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use `has_and_belongs_to_many` any ways. It's more or less out of favour at this point.